# Stop script after setting value

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have written the below script with the help of this forum (Thank You).

What I am trying to do is look for a user on each GC replica and once found write that server name to the `Set-adserversetting -preferredserver` option.

The only thing I can't work out is how to stop it after it successfully writes the value the first time. It runs through each GC and sets the value to each of them in turn.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I have put in some write-host commands for testing but will be removed once I have it resolved.

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory

    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $ConnectionURI -Authentication kerberos       
    Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber -warningaction silentlycontinue| Out-Null

$GCs = get-addomaincontroller -filter {isglobalcatalog -eq $true}

foreach ($GC in $GCs)
{
    $GCendpoint = "{0}:3268" -f $GC.HostName
    $SearchResult = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(samaccountname=$ADUserName))" -Server $GCendpoint -searchbase $ADdomainDN -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if(@($SearchResult).Count -gt 0){
            $ADServer = $GC.hostname
            write-host $ADServer         
            Set-ADServerSettings -Preferredserver $adserver 
            $AD = Get-adserversettings 
            $Ads = $AD|select userpreferredglobalcatalog
            Write-host "Preferred Server - $ADs"

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `break` to exit the `foreach` loop - is that what you mean? Or `exit` if you actually want to end the entire script.

Comment: If I add break to the loop won't that stop it after the first attempt even if it didn't set the value? I have about 8 GCs for it to loop through. Some of them I can't access properly so I need it to run through all GCs and once it has successfully set the ADServerSettings I want it to stop rather than going through all of them

Comment: @MoriteUK you can set the break inside your if clause. You should check if setting the PreferredServer was succesful and if yes break. Something like this:
`if(Set-ADServerSettings -PreferredServer $adserver){break;}`

Comment: @MoriteUK The code inside the `if` block only executes if you've found a good GC, so if you place the `break` *inside* the `if` block, it won't break until it has done it's job. `break` of course needs to go *after* the line where you call `Set-ADServerSettings`

Comment: @MoriteUK Microsoft's Technet has a good explaination of conditional breaks at [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847873(v=wps.620).aspx)